# Code::Blocks: Code Blocks IDE does not read backslashes from a .vcsproj file

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am importing a C++ project that was created in `Visual Studio` on a `Windows` machine, into my `Code::Blocks` IDE using `Linux Ubuntu 13.10`. After importing the `.sln` file, `Code::Blocks` was able to detect the files but it could not read them due to the `\`'s in the `.vcsproj` file (which was created in `VS` on the `Windows` machine).

After replacing all of the `\`'s in the `.vcsproj` with `/`'s, everything works fine, but was this the correct solution? This is an open source project, so I wonder if there is a platform-independent solution, or should we expect each user to build the project themselves? Should the `.vcsproj` or `.sln` file be excluded from the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of cross platform development!

Consider using something like [Cmake](http://cmake.org) or [Premake](http://industriousone.com/premake) to generate the project files for the platform you are developing on.

This way any developer can take the CMake\Premake script and generate vcxproj files if they are on Windows or Codeblocks proj files for Linux/Windows, or even Gnu Makefiles if they are so inclined.